# Spring MVC Session Being Invalidated, but Counter Not Reset

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I am trying to learn something about the session mgmt aspects of Spring MVC, and am running this [Example](http://springsourcery.org/springSourcery/content/viewContent,1,34.html?random=2602).  However, the "ResetController" is not resetting the counter of the form object to 0.  I'm certain the session is being invalidated (If I call **session.invalidate()** twice, the 2nd call throws ***Session already invalidated***).

Do I have a misconception, or maybe the blog poster made an error?

Comment: Did you update your code to the comments in the blog.  Looks like someone found a bug in the code at some point

Comment: Yes, thanks.  I noted that, too, but it didn't make a difference.